# Login only via Ubuntu Wayland possible and User is missing in Login List, Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, login, login-screen, gdm, wayland

After update from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, all works fine. My notebook has two users there have access to the client with a separate user profile.

After *Unsubscribe* from my profile, is it impossible to log in again after a restart or similar. The user is not existent on the user access login page. But it is possible to use the function "not visible", add my user name, password and switch to "Login via Wayland".

[image]

How is it possible to get my user back on the default user access list and log in about the default way without the Wayland way?

#### What I tried?

I tried to switch via the Cogwheel on the right bottom side, but the default login via "Ubuntu" instead of "Ubuntu via Wayland" will not work. I'm back on the login screen. Also, I tried to read and change the `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and shut off the Wayland option via `WaylandEnable=false`, but no changes.

I created a new "Guest" account, and it logs in fine. That confirms that there's something in the original account's home folder causing the login loop. So I mean, the problem is my `/home/username` directory. But I can't find any problem. I search for `*authority` file, but there is no file inside this directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try several things in my home directory because all other users work fine. The following steps help you to get out of the login loop and solve it to login via the default way 'Ubuntu' (without Wayland).

### Note

Xorg and Wayland are display servers (not to be confused with display managers, like lightdm or gdm3).

### Current display server

The following command prompt out the current display server for the user, 'wayland' or ' x11' (gdm3).

```
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
```

If you have more than one display manager installed, to check which one you are using, type at a terminal the command.

```
cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
```

This list in my client the  `/usr/sbin/gdm3`.

### Switch

Now I switch back to gdm3, the following command is helpful.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

After reboot, you should have the possibility to log in again via the default way, without Wayland.

### User list

However, my user is still missing from the list of users on the log in screen. Now I find the problem with the help of a list of all users.

```
cat /etc/passwd
```

That lists all users and additional information, like User-ID, Visible name and default Shell. On this list, I find my user name and the path to the default Shell. In my installation was it Fish, `/usr/bin/fish`.

Now I change them via `usermod -s /bin/bash username`. You must be run as root though.

Now, the user is back in the visible list. Also, it is now possible to change the profile image and the settings to each other user profile.